# Access 2010 vba - import from excel numbers, letters or blank spaces

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I'm still new with the vba. I have an database that with the help of others peoples I've finally able to do validation check when importing. However, I can get check done with numbers as text, but if I need alpha character or if the cell is blank I'm stuck. This is what I have for numbers as text. I need two checks: 1) accept alphanumeric or blank (null) and 2)numeric or blank (null).

```
   Function chk2(A As String) As Boolean
   Dim i As Integer, l As Integer, c As String
   l = Len(A)
     If l = 4 Then
      chk2 = True
         For i = 1 To l
         c = Mid(A, i, 1)
         If Not (c >= "0" And c <= "9") Then
            chk2 = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    End If
   End Function
```

This one works fine as long as there are characters to fill in each row/cell.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning a boolean value, you should only return a true value if everything has executed correctly, that way you aren't getting a false positive if something fails. 
You could use a check if the cell has 0 length for a blank cell, i.e. If Len = 0
What you are doing in your If Not statement is checking if the ascii value of c is between the ascii values of 0 and 9 so you can use or statements to check if it is between a and z or A and Z or if there is a space which is character 32 - Chr(32) :

```
Function chk2(A As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, l As Integer, c As String

    chk2 = false

    l = Len(A)
    If l = 0 then
        'do something if the cell is blank
        chk2 = true
    ElseIf l = 4 Then
        For i = 1 To l
            c = Mid(A, i, 1)

            If Not ((c >= "0" And c <= "9") Or (c >= "a" And c <= "z") Or (c >= "A" And C <= "Z") Or c = Chr(32)) Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i

        chk2=true
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey! Is it possible If Len = 0 to not do anything, leave as blank? Or do I have to do something?

Comment: Yes, you can leave it blank

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey! I will give it a try.

Comment: I have another issue with the code (same db). I can't get the above to accept just certain letters. For instance, If Not (c = "A") And (c = "C") And (c = "S") Then chk2=False. Maybe, I'm just slow or something.

Comment: Also, I'm still having problems with nulls, I can put "0" with some, but if it requires a alpha then I'm having issues too.

Comment: For the If Not (c = "A") And... the Not only applies for the next variable (in this case the return of c = "A") not the entire line, so you will need to put parenthesis around the entire statement Not ((c = "A") And (c = "C") And (c = "S"))

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks again Jeffrey! The parenthesis worked. My last comment is still around "Blank" and "0". Places where there should be a alpha character should not have a "0". For example If Not ((c = "A") Or (c = "B") Or (c = "C") Or (c = "D") Or (c = "E") Or (c = "F") Then chk12=False. I cannot put a "0" just to by pass the error check, but if I leave the space with nothing then it does not pass the error check either. Does this make sense or not?

Comment: Right now, if you're using exactly what I wrote, chk2 will only return true if there is nothing being passed in A or if there are 4 characters being passed that pass your character check. So if you want it to check if you passed a 0 character, you could add another elseIf that just checks the string i.e. "ElseIf A=0 Then" or you could do another length check if you need to check for other characters "ElseIf l=1 Then"

Comment: Oh crap! It worked!!!! Thank you very much Jeffrey! You are a lifesaver. I wish I could give you all the credit you deserve.

Comment: for some reason this function allows any alpha character, and passes the error check when it shouldn't. 'Function chk12(A As String) As Boolean
'Check CRESIZE - 1 alphanumeric
Dim i As Integer, l As Integer, c As String
chk12 = False
l = Len(A)
If l = 0 Then
    chk12 = True
       For i = 1 To l
        If Not ((c = "A") And (c = "B") And (c = "C") And (c = "D") And (c = "E") And (c = "F")) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
      chk12 = True
End If
End Function'